# Is this also a carpenter ant?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, ant, pest-control

I live in Dayton, Ohio.  I've found large-ish ants in my kitchen, and I'm wondering if they're carpenter ants.
I realize there's been a few questions about carpenter ant identification, but in my defense, this one comes with video: https://youtu.be/HGWertws0oo

Picture, with penny for reference:
[image: ant over a penny]
See the video for better shots (mixed in with bad shots, haha).

Is this a carpenter ant, or something more benign?

Answer (score -1):

It is a carpenter worker ant. They usually live in outdoors , If they build a colony inside your house,then it will be a huge trouble to you to patch the walls since, they are capable of creating larger holes and cracks in the wall .I don't know what exactly is your doubt? If you can you can elaborate your specific point.